# SQL GROUP BY for nested select statements

Tags: sql, oracle

Previously I had this query -

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT ds.CLIENTID),
  COUNT(ds.FACID),
  (SUM(ds.NETARREARS) + SUM(ds.TAXARREARS)),
  SUM(ds.UNEARNEDINCOME), 
  SUM(ds.INCOMESUSPENSE) , 
  SUM(ds.VATSUSPENSE) , 
  SUM(ds.PREPAIDDEPOSIT), 
  SUM(ds.NETFUTURE) , 
  SUM(ds.NETEXPOSURE), 
  SUM(ds.PROVISION), 
  SUM(ds.FACILITYSECURITYAMOUNT), 
  SUM(ds.PROVISIONAMOUNTCFWD) 

FROM 
  DAILY_SUMMARY ds 

WHERE
  ds.SUMMARY_DATE = :reportDate AND 
  ds.FACSTS IN('F','L','A') AND 
  ds.PERSTS = 'N';
```

But later we decided to drop the columns

1. `ds.UNEARNEDINCOME` (4th select item from top)
2. `ds.PROVISION`(10th select item from top)

Because we have alternative queries to fetch those, which are -

1. `SELECT SUM(tcs.DUEAMT) FROM TCRENT tcs WHERE tcs.FACID = ds.FACID AND tcs.DUETYPE = 'INT' AND tcs.DUEDATE > :reportDate`
2. `SELECT sum(pup.PROVISIONAMT) FROM PROVISION_UPLOAD pup WHERE pup.PROVISIONDATE < :reportDate AND pup.FACID = ds.FACID`

So the final query is -

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT ds.CLIENTID),
  COUNT(ds.FACID),
  (SUM(ds.NETARREARS) + SUM(ds.TAXARREARS)),
  (SELECT SUM(tcs.DUEAMT) FROM TCRENT tcs WHERE tcs.FACID = ds.FACID AND tcs.DUETYPE = 'INT' AND tcs.DUEDATE > :reportDate) AS income, 
  SUM(ds.INCOMESUSPENSE) , 
  SUM(ds.VATSUSPENSE) , 
  SUM(ds.PREPAIDDEPOSIT), 
  SUM(ds.NETFUTURE) , 
  SUM(ds.NETEXPOSURE), 
  (SELECT sum(pup.PROVISIONAMT) FROM PROVISION_UPLOAD pup WHERE pup.PROVISIONDATE < :reportDate AND pup.FACID = ds.FACID) AS prov, 
  SUM(ds.FACILITYSECURITYAMOUNT), 
  SUM(ds.PROVISIONAMOUNTCFWD) 

FROM 
  DAILY_SUMMARY ds 

WHERE
  ds.SUMMARY_DATE = '10-FEB-15' AND 
  ds.FACSTS IN('F','L','A') AND 
  ds.PERSTS = 'N';
```

But now the problem is integrating those 2 queries with the master query, it give the error -

> not a single-group group function

means it requires GROUP BY. I tried grouping and even generated the SQL Developer's suggested group by but it is inaccurate as it is incomplete -

```
group by COUNT(DISTINCT, COUNT(ds.FACID), (SUM(ds.NETARREARS), (SELECT,SUM(ds.INCOMESUSPENSE), 
SUM(ds.VATSUSPENSE), SUM(ds.PREPAIDDEPOSIT), SUM(ds.NETFUTURE), SUM(ds.NETEXPOSURE), (SELECT
```

Just FYI - the master query works fine if the group by clause and the new 2 queries are commented.

Can anyone help me with this?

UPDATE - Sample results screenshot

[image: Sample result]

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: is this still open? i never understand why to use selects in the select list...

Comment: left join instead?

Comment: yeah it is open and yes, I tried left join.. but then I'm getting 168 for COUNT(ds.FACID) instead of 8. I am able to resolve it by COUNT(DISTINCT ds.FACID). But the SUM(ds.INCOMESUSPENSE) and other amounts increase, which I cannot manage by adding a DISTINCT to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your subqueries are *correlated subqueries*:

```
(SELECT sum(pup.PROVISIONAMT)
 FROM PROVISION_UPLOAD pup
 WHERE pup.PROVISIONDATE < :reportDate AND
       pup.FACID = ds.FACID
-------------------^
) AS prov,
```

This correlation clause is using `ds.FACID`.  However, this column is not available *after* aggregating.

I'm not sure what results you really want, so it is difficult to propose a solution.  Perhaps you want another reference to `ds` in the subquery, as opposed to a correlated subquery.

Comment: I debugged the program with the previous version - before dropping the columns and got this record. This runs within a for loop. This is the original result I expect (as in query 1 of my question) .

[2, 4, 1577670.0, 1025977.03, 382470.51, 72444.0, 0.0, 6840996.0, 6937774.46, 0.0, 0.0, 1368234.28]